# How to simulate a time delay in a gRPC response in java tests

Tags: java, mocking, grpc

I'm running a timeout test and I want to simulate a time-lagged gRPC integration. Is it possible to do this?

I know what I can use Thread.sleep(), but don't understand where I can insert waiting in mocking gRPC.

Please let me know if the question is vague or you need more information.